# Angular 2 routing, adding child routes causes route not to work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Whiles playing with angular 2 routes using the latest version, I noticed that adding a child route cause /admin route below not to work

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';
import {AdminChildComponent} from './admin-child.component';

import {productRoutes} from "../product/product.routes";

export const adminRoutes : Routes =[
  {
    path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,
    children:[
      {path:"/child", component:AdminChildComponent}
    ]
  }
];

export const adminRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes);
```

Once I remove below, applications wors just fine, soon as I add it I get console error

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes:
>   'admin'

```
   children:[
      {path:"/child", component:AdminChildComponent}
    ]
```

Need help possibly understanding why am getting this error. Totally confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because:

As here it is clearly seen that **AdminComponent** has children. It means **AdminComponent** will have ***router-outlet*** somewhere in template.

Now the thing is, whenever ***router-outlet*** is used, it requires a **view**. In your routing case, it doesn't have any proper/primary child route. So you need to set it as shown below,

```
export const adminRoutes : Routes =[
  {
    path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,
    children:[

      { path: '', redirectTo: 'child', pathMatch: 'full'}, //<----- here

      {path:"child", component:AdminChildComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

NOTE: Changed `/child` to `child`. Why? Because angular2 router itself adds `/` between parent and its child routes. So here you don't need `/`.

Comment: I failed to understand why such a config is required. Nevertheless, adding your suggested {path: '', ... } produces an exception EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'child'

Comment: I have given explanation in my answer why such route is required.

Comment: I understood your explanation and also took your answer into consideration and compared to other routes with child routes. Yes it appears you always need an empty route which either redirects or routes to a component. Problem with mine was "/child" instead of just "child"

Comment: I was aware of that. But still I suggested you with `/child` but it should be `child` only.